# Vue2 trying to set chart title

Tags: vuejs2, chart.js

Does not work like this:

```html
<template>
  <Bar
    :chart-options="chartOptions"
    :chart-data="$attrs['chart-data'] || chartData"
    :chart-id="chartId"
    :dataset-id-key="datasetIdKey"
    :plugins="plugins"
    :css-classes="cssClasses"
    :styles="styles"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs/legacy'
import 'chart.js/auto'

export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: { Bar },
  props: {
    chartId: {
      type: String,
      default: 'bar-chart',
    },
    datasetIdKey: {
      type: String,
      default: 'label',
    },
    width: {
      type: Number,
      default: 400,
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: 400,
    },
    cssClasses: {
      default: '',
      type: String,
    },
    styles: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
    plugins: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {},
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Custom Chart Title',
        },
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

tried editing even with this: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-ully-2wst65?file=/src/components/Bar.vue
but nothing works.

All info gathered from: https://vue-chartjs.org/api/
Registration of components are not needed if you import auto.

maybe some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are using v2 syntax in v3, the internal plugins like the tooltip, title, legend and decimation have been moved from the `options` namespace to the `options.plugins` namespace.

So you need to nest the title options in a plugins object within the options object. Then it will work

Comment: im blind as hell. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

For those like me, who are looking for a solution using `vue-chartjs` V4.
To show the `Title` you need to pass the plugin object, for example:

```
plugins: {
  type: Array,
  default: () => [Title]
}
```

and then pass into the `chartOptions` props the `title` configuration, for example:

```
chartOptions: {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  plugins: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart Title",
    },
  },
}
```

[sandBox full example](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-shtern-elf25v?file=/src/components/Bar.vue:1615-1803):